# When can I run a shell script with command ". shellscript" in bash,ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

If I have a script "shellscript" in /usr/bin directory(It can also be a script of an installed program). When I run command "shellscript" (from anywhere , home or other directory) in terminal, it runs perfectly but when I use ". shellscript" , then also this file executes.
I know we can use ". /path/to/script/shellscript" to run it but if its in /usr/bin , can we use direct command without path?
Is it safe to run?
Can we run programs in such a way?
I need explanation. If yes then why? If Not then why? Should not then why?

Comment: Have you checked the manual? I'm about to do that now.

Comment: Oh, look: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins says: "`. filename [arguments]` - Read and execute commands from the *filename* argument in the current shell context. If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find *filename*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bash shell searches the directories listed in the `PATH` variable in both `shellscript` and `. shellscript` cases. The main difference is that when using `.` (or equivalently `source`) to start a script, a new shell process is not created for interpreting the script. This is sometimes useful because it allows the script to define environment variables and functions that will then be available in the caller. For more details, see the [Bash manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) (`info bash`).

Comment: Does it have any drawback to use . shellscript. If we have installed a program "prog" and if i run it using command "prog" and ". prog" , is there any threat or error that may happen?

Comment: I am doing this for some program and it behaves differently? What may be the cause? What is different between them?

Comment: can you elaborate "it allows the script to define environment variables and functions that will then be available in the caller".

Comment: Does it override environment variables or something like that. @melpomene

Comment: The command "prog" and ". prog" can indeed behave differently, if "prog" is a shell script. You should use the "." to call a script only if you want the script to affect the environment of the caller.

Comment: One way to think about this is that the normal way to run a script asks the shell to start a new shell process and ask it to interpret the script, but using ". script" makes the current shell process to interpret commands from the script. In a way, the command line is replaced by the contents of the file. Please read the manual page, and do some experiments.